# Nifi:Initialization in nifi custom processors

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I  use   nifi  1.3.0   and  i   have  added  one  property  descriptor  Directory and   2  Relationships  (failure and   success) but  for  some  reason  when i  build  this  program and   export  nar  fail  in nifi  lib  directory,  after  processing nifi and  placeing MyProcessor i  got  processor  without property and  relationships. here is my  code  and relative processor  picture:

```
protected void init(final ProcessorInitializationContext context) {
final List<PropertyDescriptor> properties = new ArrayList<>();
properties.add(DIRECTORY);

this.properties = Collections.unmodifiableList(properties);

final Set<Relationship> relationships = new HashSet<>();
relationships.add(REL_SUCCESS);
relationships.add(REL_FAILURE);
this.relationships = Collections.unmodifiableSet(relationships);
}
```

1. Do  you  have  any better   idea  how  can i improve it?
   here  is  picture:
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the methods that return the properties and relationships:

```
@Override
public Set<Relationship> getRelationships() {
  return this.relationships;
}

@Override
protected List<PropertyDescriptor> getSupportedPropertyDescriptors() {
  return this.properties;
}
```